# Como somar um array com ele mesmo mais dados?

Tags: php, cakephp-2

É o seguinte galera. Eu tenho um for e dentro dele eu tenho um array ($smses) que recebe ($smses = $smses + 'os dados da minha aplicação'). O problema é que isso não funciona, gostaria de saber como eu add os novos dados a partir do novo indice.

```
     if ($campanha['Smse']['entity'] == 0) {
                for ($i=0; $i < $tamanho; $i++) { 

                    $smses =  $smses + $this->Phone->find('list', array(                      
                        'fields' => array('Phone.phone'),
                        'conditions' => array(
                            $conditions,
                            'Phone.type' => 2,
                            'Phone.phone !=' => '',
                            ),
                        'joins' => array(
                            array(
                                'table' => 'contacts',
                                'alias' => 'Contact',
                                'type' => 'LEFT',
                                'conditions' => array('Phone.contact_id = Contact.id')
                                ),        
                            array(
                                'table' => 'prospects',
                                'alias' => 'Prospect',
                                'type' => 'LEFT',
                                'conditions' => array('Prospect.contact_id = Contact.id')
                                ),
                            ),
                        ));
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não pode "somar" arrays dessa forma. Para fundir dois ou mais arrays você deve usar a função [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php).

No seu caso ficaria algo assim:

```
$smses =  array_merge($smses, $this->Phone->find('list', array(                      
    'fields' => array('Phone.phone'),
    'conditions' => array(
        $conditions,
        'Phone.type' => 2,
        'Phone.phone !=' => '',
        ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'contacts',
            'alias' => 'Contact',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array('Phone.contact_id = Contact.id')
            ),        
        array(
            'table' => 'prospects',
            'alias' => 'Prospect',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array('Prospect.contact_id = Contact.id')
            ),
        ),
)));
```

Comment: Obrigado! Funfou aq.